# Non-interactive non-modal UIPopoverController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

Is there any way to have a `UIPopoverController` purely as a visual element that does not create a mode on top of the current view? I'd love to have a popover to display a message along with a contextual arrow, but not itself respond to events and not interfere with the interaction on the view behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is to use the `passthroughViews` property of `UIPopoverController` to let touches pass through the popover view. It won't pass touches through the popover itself, but can be used to make them non-modal.

For a more customizable approach, something like https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover might be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the open source API's like these:

http://code4app.net/ios/PopTip-View/4f6d89f86803faed41000000
OR
https://github.com/ajerez/AJNotificationView (uses a banner instead of a popover for messages)

Comment: I'd like it to look like the standard `UIPopoverController` if it can't actually be a real one.